# I keep getting an error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'TweetID' referenced before assignment [SOLVED]

Tags: python, sql, tweepy, pgadmin

I'm having a problem with an error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'TweetID' referenced before assignment.

Now please, don't crap on the layout and functions of this code. I posted the entire code just in case since I don't know where the mistake is. I'm still new and I know it makes no sense, but 99% works, except this part. I really can't find the reason of the error, I know what it means but I don't see the problem.

A little background: I have to pull a certain tweet from a database and accept or reject it. When Accepted, it tweets to twitter. When rejected, you leave an explanation why. Kind of like a moderator. Moderator ID and StationID (where the tweet was posted) are also sent to the database.

If you need more info I'm happy to supply. Other constructive feedback is also appreciated, but I'm a real newbie so I can't deal with anything too complicated :)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Users\vince\Desktop\Python Code Project Steam\Twitterzuil\MOD.py", line 74, in 
Process()
File "D:\Users\vince\Desktop\Python Code Project Steam\Twitterzuil\MOD.py", line 68, in Process
Accept()
File "D:\Users\vince\Desktop\Python Code Project Steam\Twitterzuil\MOD.py", line 32, in Accept
TweetID = TweetID()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'TweetID' referenced before assignment

```
import psycopg2
import time


conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="localhost",
    database="postgres",
    user="postgres",
    password="")

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT (Tweet, naam, inhoud, datum, tijd) from Bericht2 WHERE acceptrejectposted is NULL ORDER BY tijd ASC LIMIT 1")
result = cur.fetchall();

#login
mod_id = int(input("Geef uw moderator ID: "))

#VIEW TWEET
print(result)

def TweetID():
    cur.execute("SELECT (Tweet) from Bericht2 WHERE acceptrejectposted is NULL ORDER BY tijd ASC LIMIT 1")
    tweet_id = cur.fetchall()
    return tweet_id

def Accept():
    tweet_id = TweetID()
    cur.execute(f"UPDATE Bericht2 SET acceptrejectposted = 1 WHERE tweet = {tweet_id}")
    cur.execute(f"UPDATE Bericht2 SET moderator2mod_id = {mod_id} WHERE tweet = {tweet_id}")
    print('TWEET ACCEPTED')
    conn.commit()
    PostTweet()

def Reject():
    tweet_id = TweetID()
    cur.execute(f"UPDATE Bericht2 SET acceptrejectposted = 0 WHERE tweet = {tweet_id}")
    cur.execute(f"UPDATE Bericht2 SET moderator2mod_id = {mod_id} WHERE tweet = {tweet_id}")
    Opmerking = input("Opmerking?")
    cur.execute(f"UPDATE Bericht2 SET opmerking = '{Opmerking}' WHERE tweet = {tweet_id}")
    print('TWEET REJECTED')
    conn.commit()

def PostTweet():
    tweet_id = TweetID()
    cur.execute("SELECT (inhoud) from Bericht2 WHERE acceptrejectposted = 1 ORDER BY tijd ASC LIMIT 1")
    Tweet = cur.fetchall()
    cur.execute(f"UPDATE Bericht2 SET acceptrejectposted = 2 WHERE tweet = {tweet_id}")
    conn.commit()
    print("Posting to twitter...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Posted!")

def Process():
    AccRej = input("Accept or Reject? ")
    if AccRej == "Accept":
        Accept()
    elif AccRej == "Reject":
        Reject()
    else:
        print("Invalid")

Process()
```

Comment: For one thing, you've named your function the same thing as several variables. That ought to be causing some problems. Instead of using `TweetID = TweetID()`, you should use something like `tweet_id = TweetID()`. Keep `TweetID` for the function name, and `tweet_id` for the variable name.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin Thanks, just edited that. Do you have any idea why I'm getting the error perhaps?

Comment: That _was_ my idea of the cause of the error. Are you still getting the error message? It doesn't look like you've edited your question.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin Silly me, I was running an old one. Different error now though: psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: ...TE Bericht2 SET acceptrejectposted = 1 WHERE tweet = [(22,)] That's what tweet_id gets from the database, that annoying formatting. You helped with the old issue though, thanks for that. I thought it was just feedback haha

Comment: That password (`Dehol416!`) isn't your real password, is it? Because, if it is, you'd better change it on your account right now.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin I used a password manager but thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

As Sylvester Kruin correctly noticed, you should not mixing variable and function names. Consider snake_case for variable names:

```
def Accept():
  tweet_id = TweetID()
  cur.execute(f"UPDATE Bericht2 SET acceptrejectposted = 1 WHERE tweet = {tweet_id}")
  cur.execute(f"UPDATE Bericht2 SET moderator2mod_id = {mod_id} WHERE tweet = {tweet_id}")
  print('TWEET ACCEPTED')
  conn.commit()
  PostTweet()
```